# Retrieve all user from a LDAP group using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap, openldap

I need help on how to retrieve all users from a LDAP group.

here is my BaseDN:

```
ou=162681,ou=apps,ou=nait,ou=contexts,o=nsroot.net`
```

my search filter is:

```
(&(objectClass=organizationalPerson))`
```

the above search filter is always returning me only one user from LDAP.

Is there anyway i can get all users from that group ?

I am using java to retrieve information from LDAP.

Here is my code...

this.searchBase = "ou=162681,ou=apps,ou=nait,ou=contexts,o=nsroot.net";

String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group))";

NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase,searchFilter, searchCtls);

while (answer.hasMore()) {
   ......
}

the above serachFilter nothing from OU=162681

when I changed my filter to below to return all user whose "uid" started with sm, it is returning me only one user.

String searchFilter="(&(uid=sm*))";

My goal is to retireve all users under OU=162681

Comment: Let me know if any more information needed

Comment: This will depend on you LDAP structure. On an Active directory server you could used the baseDN as the group DN and the filter as `objectclass=group` and you can fetch the attribute `member` which returns the members of the group. Does your baseDB above point to the group whose members you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: Get all users from what group? If ou=162681... is a group, that search shouldn't return anything, unless for some reason you have the users as children of the group, which is the wrong way to do it, as it prevents users from being members if more than one group, unless you use aliases, which is an even worse solution. The users should be listed by DN in a uniqueMember or member attribute of the group.

Comment: @YSU: Yes.. All the users are under OU=162681. I did use below below filter (objectClass=group) as you mentione above. this time it does not return anything..

Comment: I have updated my code snippet above. Let me know if I am missing naything.

Comment: @EJP: Yes it is a group. It has certail users under that group.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong, as I said. Group members should be given by a DN-valued attribute. You need to redesign.

Comment: Redesign what? code or LDAP structure ?

Comment: I have a uid attribute in LDAP for each user, which is unique.I cant modify LDAP structure.

Comment: Also When I am using filter "(&(uid=sm*))" to return all user whose uid started with "sm", why it is returning only one user? Is there any LDAP SearchResult Limit ?

Comment: Obviously, you need to provide more information. Your question was " all users from a LDAP group" I really doubt that ou=162681,ou=apps,ou=nait,ou=contexts,o=nsroot.net is a group. In ALL LDAP server implementations groups would normally be named as CN=162681. Do what you want with a good browser, (Apache Studio) and then you will know what your are looking at.

Comment: @jeemster: Well I use both Apache Studio and and JXplorer. I could see objectClass=organizationalUnit, objectClass=top and ou=162681. I dont see anything else.  Pleae note I could see all users from LDAP browser. My problem is when I am trying to fetch all users from ou=162681 it gives me only one user from LDAP. when I use the same filter in lDAP browser, it gives me desired result. I am trying to understand if there are any restriction in JAVA to fetch information from LDAP

Comment: There could be administrative restrictions on the number of entries returned (I would expect to see an error in this case, though) or there could be ACL restrictions. I just tested http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/BasicJNDISearch and it retruns all users that match the filter (objectClass=organizationalPerson) in my test tree (openDJ).